# How to fix the cursor size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a **textarea** with different **font-size** and **line-height**.
I made it for spacing between lines in **textarea**.

When I press enter inside **textarea** I get the big cursor.
How I can fix this problem?

```css
textarea {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 92px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

[image]

I've found several questions that are very similar. But these solutions don't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the large value of the `line-height` property that's causing this - change it to something nearer the font size and your cursor will reduce in size.

The `line-height` property is mainly good for two things: vertically centering single lines of text, and increasing line spacing, but the latter is problematic in a text field.

Comment: I know that line-height causes is causing this, but without it I can't make more spacing between lines in TextArea. Is there other way how to change line-height to solve this?

Comment: Not without a hack of some kind. Why do you need line-spacing in a text area, if this is for user input?

Answer (score 3):

There is no property regarding size of cursor but still you can use custom cursors by adding an image like:

```
cursor: url('cursor.png');
```

Comment: It was a good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work. cursor: url('cursor.png') changes only the cursor on textarea, but not inside.